# How to use HttpWebRequest GET method in Twitter API

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get Status from Twitter Home TimeLine, and it failed.

I have no problem when use POST method when update status, and it worked.
Here, code sample:

```
$post_body = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("status=" + $status); 
[System.Net.HttpWebRequest] $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json");
$request.Method = "POST";
$request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $oauth_authorization);
$request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
$body = $request.GetRequestStream();
$body.write($post_body, 0, $post_body.length);
$body.flush();
$body.close();
$response = $request.GetResponse();
```

But, when use GET method to read Home Timeline , i always get error message.

```
Exception calling "GetRequestStream" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type."
At line:42 char:1
+ $response = $request.GetRequestStream()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProtocolViolationException
```

Here the code i use:

```
[System.Net.HttpWebRequest] $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json");
$request.Method = "GET";
$request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $oauth_authorization);
$request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
$response = $request.GetRequestStream();
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Change `$response = $request.GetRequestStream()` to `$response = $request.GetResponse()`

Comment: `GetResponse()` throws the same error as `GetRequestStream()` did?

Comment: yes. GetResponse() throws the same error as GetRequestStream()

Comment: @jisaak , i have tried change method from GET to POST, but still throws same error.

Comment: @jisaak , Thank you. With GetResponse and GET/POST method, it error. It solved with GetRequestStream() with POST method

Comment: your welcome. you should just search a little on so before you post your question ;-).